# Exact kernel source code on Fedora

Tags: fedora, kernel, source-code

Could you please share how to acquire the corresponding kernel source code for `4.5.5-300.fc24.x86_64`?  I cannot find it in `/usr/src/kernels` when installing that on Fedora 24.

Comment: If this is your currently installed kernel you can get the src rpm with ` dnf  download --source kernel`

Comment: thx let me have a try. one more thing is how to update/upgrade to 4.11.12-100.fc24.x86_64 or latest FC version. as I tried 'yum -y update' to update all it is still 4.5.5-300.fc24.x86_64. Need I do upgrade or other actions?

Comment: yes, `dnf update` should get and install the 4.11.12 kernel binary, but you will need to reboot. If comes from the fedora updates repository which is normally enabled. See file `/etc/yum.repos.d/fedora-updates.repo`